# Adding unique records to a listbox from another listbox

Tags: vba, excel

I am hoping someone can help me out because I don't often code in Excel VBA.  I have two `Listbox` and a `CommandButton` on a `UserForm`, which adds selected records from the first `ListBox` to the second.  The range in the first `ListBox` is kind of long and so users of the form will generally select a couple records, hit the *Add* button, and then scroll down the first `ListBox` to select more records to add.  The problem is, only the ones that have been added last will actually be recognized and used to generate reports even though all of the selected records appear in the second `ListBox`.  Here is my current code for the button that adds the records to the second `ListBox`:

```
Private Sub AddButton_Click()

    For i = 0 To Listbox1.ListCount - 1
        If Listbox1.Selected(i) = True Then Listbox2.AddItem Listbox2.List(i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

How can I populate the second `ListBox` so that it will include every record selected no matter how many times the add button is used?

Comment: You say "Even though all of the selected records appear in the second listbox" Do they, or do they not? Is the second listbox lists of records what is used to generate reports? I feel like maybe something important is missing from this question.

Comment: That's the strange part.  They all appear in the second listbox in the userform but only the ones that were added last are the ones that seem to get recognized.  I have a second button that 'runs' the reports based on the selections in the second listbox and so every time the reports are run, they only run the ones based on the records that were added last.  Hopefully, that clarifies better.

Comment: I suspec tthe issue is with the reports based on the selections in the second list box. I suspect that only the last added items are "Selected" so instead of running the reports based on "Selection" you should run them based on their presence in the second list box (Selected or not) or... select them all programatically before running that code?